# Relative positioning within pgfplots axis environment using metric unites

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to position independently of the x- and y-scale of the axis environment, for instance, a line 1 cm above another line. The start and end points of the line are only known in the axis coordinate system. My minimal example shows the none expected behavior:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xmin=-3,
    xmax=11,
    ymin=-3,
    ymax=11,
    x = 0.6cm,
    y = 0.6cm,
    axis x line=center,
    axis y line=center]

    \draw[->] (1,1) -- (8,1);
    \draw[-,blue] (1,1) ++(0,1cm) -- ($(8,1) + (0,1cm)$);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can save coordinates inside the `axis` environments and then draw the second line outside.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xmin=-3,
    xmax=11,
    ymin=-3,
    ymax=11,
    x = 0.6cm,
    y = 0.6cm,
    axis x line=center,
    axis y line=center]

    \draw[->] (1,1) coordinate(a) -- (8,1) coordinate (b);
  \end{axis}

    \draw[-,blue] (a) ++(0,1cm) -- ($(b) + (0,1cm)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

On another note, it seems that normalizing  by the unit vector works at least in this case:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xmin=-3,
    xmax=11,
    ymin=-3,
    ymax=11,
    x = 0.6cm,
    y = 0.6cm,
    axis x line=center,
    axis y line=center
]

    \draw[->] (1,1) coordinate(a) -- (8,1) coordinate (b);
    % note that axis cs: is required
    \draw[-,blue] (axis cs:1,1+1cm/\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/y})  -- (axis cs:8,1 + 1cm/\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/y});
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I voted your answer up. However, this is more a workaround because my figures are more complex as the given example. So I have to define a lot of coordinates and the tikz source code lines cannot be grouped appropriately.

Comment: @hzhr I added another possibility, though it's still a bit clunky. There might be better options though, I'm not really an expert on this area.